# React/Jest - mock fetch and wait for componentDidMount to re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, enzyme, jestjs

I'm playing around with react and jest and I've came to the following situation where I simply cannot figure it out how should I do it.

**Todo.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import TodoItem from './TodoItem';
import {fetchTodoItems} from '../helpers/todo';

class Todo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            todos: [],
            error: false,
            loading: true
        };

        this.updateMockState = this.updateMockState.bind(this);
    }

    updateMockState() {
        this.setState({
            todos: [{ id: 8101, text: "Cook fresh food", status: "completed" }],
            loading: false
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // TODO: add error handling

        fetchTodoItems().then(response => {
            this.setState({
                todos: response.data,
                loading: false
            })
        }, error => {});
    }

    render() {
        let content;

        // TODO: add error handling

        if (this.state.loading) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <button id="update-data" onClick={this.updateMockState}>Update State</button>
                    </div>
                    <p>Todos are being fetched...</p>
                </div>
            );
        }

        return (
            content ||
            <div>
                <div>
                    <button id="update-data" onClick={this.updateMockState}>Update State</button>
                </div>
                <p><b>{this.state.todos.length}</b> todos fetched so far</p>
                {this.state.todos.map(
                    (todo) => <TodoItem key={todo.id} id={todo.id} status={todo.status} text={todo.text} />)}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

Todo.proptypes = {
    timeout: PropTypes.number
};

export default Todo;
```

**Todo.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import { mount, shallow, render } from 'enzyme';
import Todo from '../components/Todo';
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json';

// TODO: remove sinon from NPM packages

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

const todos = { data: [{
    "id": 4404,
    "status": "active",
    "text": "Shopping List"
}, {
    "id": 7162,
    "status": "completed",
    "text": "Time Registration"
}]};

describe('Todo', () => {
    it('calls mock API', async () => {
        fetch = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(todos));
        const spy = jest.spyOn(Todo.prototype, 'componentDidMount');

        var component = mount(<Todo timeout={2000} />);
        component.instance().componentDidMount();
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();

        expect(toJson(component)).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

As you can see Todo component is a simple component that inside componentDidMount calls an API, get the response and displays. While waiting for the api call, some info is shown... There's also a button for dummy state update but that's not important for now.

fetchTodoItems (file is todo.js)

```
export const fetchTodoItems = () => {
    return fetch("data/todo.json").then(res => res.json());
};
```

My problem is the following:

- I want to do a snapshot testing on Todo component as follows:

  1. First, right on render (before API call)
  2. Right after API call has finished with success

On 1st I'm supposed to see no todo items, but on 2nd I should see my todo items.

Here is TodoItem

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const TodoItem = (props) => {
    let htmlClass = [];
    if (props.status === 'completed') {
        htmlClass.push("todo-completed");
    }

    return (
        <ul>
            <p className={htmlClass.join(" ")}>
                <small>[#{props.id}]</small> {props.text} <i>({props.status})</i>
            </p>
        </ul>
    );
}

TodoItem.proptypes = {
    id: PropTypes.number.required,
    text: PropTypes.string.required,
    status: PropTypes.string.required
};

export default TodoItem;
```

So far I've tried the following:

- pure snapshot testing with expect(component.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot() - doesn't show results after API call
- jest.spyON... the method is called but after that toMatchSnapshot still shows 1st snapshot with no data
- return promise().then(... still no results

Any help?

**EDIT:**

If I remove API call from componentDidMount and use only setState, then snapshot testing shows todos items (without 1st case where it should say that **todos are being fetched...**) Why?? Shouldn't be the same?

If then only the promises are the root cause, how can I wait for all promises to finish?

Comment: Try adding a `wrapper.update()`. This forces your component to re-render ([see docs](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/update.html)). Does this give you the expected results?

Comment: Tried that too, it doesn't work

Comment: I'm also running into this issue. I want to be able to wait for the `componentDidMount` function to run so that I can test the changes that were done to the component in that function. I cannot figure out what to wait for (async) to ensure my code tests the mounted component.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to wait for the last event(promise) if any in the queue to be resolved and then do a component instance update ?

```
const allOver = () => new Promise((resolve) => setImmediate(resolve));

describe('Todo', () => {
    it('calls mock API', async () => {
        fetch = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(todos));
        var component = mount(<Todo timeout={2000} />);
        await allOver();
        component.update();
        expect(toJson(component)).toMatchSnapshot();
    });

});
```

Comment: just wondering why the allOver is declared outside of the describe?